# How to toggle button icon and description javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my problem. I need on click to change button icon and on another click to go to original state, like +,- and span description like home/back
i dont know what to do. Pleas help.
Here is html...

```
<div class="navbar-left left">
    <button   class="toggle btn mr2 white " >
              <i  class="fa fa-home fa-2x   "></i>
              <span class="mobile-hide  ">Home</a>
    </button>
          </div>
```

and bad js

```
if ($('.toggle').hasClass('fa fa-home fa-2x')) {
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('fa fa-home ').html('<span  class="mobile-hide  ">Home</a>');

} else($('.toggle').hasClass('fa fa-home ')) {
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('fa fa-home fa-2x ').html('<span  class="mobile-hide  ">Back</a>');
}
toggleMenu();
});
```

Comment: You should include what is actually going wrong. This will help people help you!

Answer (score 2):

You can

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $('.toggle').click(function () {
        var $i = $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-2x');
        $(this).find('span.mobile-hide').html($i.hasClass('fa-2x') ? 'Home' : 'Back')
    })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-left left">
    <button class="toggle btn mr2 white" >
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="mobile-hide">Home</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `.hasClass()` to check for a single class Name.

In order to check for many class names I guess is better get the class attribute string and check with `.indexOf()`

```
  if ($('.toggle').attr("class").indexOf('fa fa-home fa-2x') != -1) {
```

The same happens with toggleClass. You have to break it down:

```
 $('.toggle').toggleClass('fa').toggleClass('fa-home').toggleClass('fa-2x')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this effect with the `::after` pseudo-element. Just change the `content` property as appropriate based on some class on the button.

A simplified example:

```js
$(function () {

  $('#toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
  });
  
});
```

```css
.icon::after {
  content: '+';
}

.text::after {
  content: 'Home';
}

.on .icon::after {
  content: '-'
}

.on .text::after {
  content: 'Back'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle">
  <i class="icon"></i>
  <span class="text"></span>
</button>
```